# GOPRIVATE and private git repository for go mod

Tags: git, go, ssh, bitbucket, go-modules

Tried to `go mod tidy` or `go mod download`
on my old organization, [all I need to do](//golang.cafe/blog/how-to-fix-go-mod-unknown-revision.html) is just to set `GOPRIVATE`, add ssh public key to the github/bitbucket/gitlab, set `.ssh/config` to which `IdentityFile` to be used to connect for custom domain, then set `.gitconfig` something like this:

```
go env -w GOPRIVATE="github.com/xxx/*"

# .gitconfig
[url "git@github.com:/xxx/"]
     insteadOf = https://github.com/xxx/
```

but this other organization won't work (using bitbucket), tried using auth key or ssh still got problem when doing `go mod tidy/download`

```
go env -w GOPRIVATE="bitbucket.xxx/*,bitbucket.xxx:9022/*" 
# 9022 is their ssh port used for cloning a repo

# .gitconfig
#[url "https://:ACCTOKEN@bitbucket.xxx/"] # ACCTOKEN is my access token
[url "ssh://git@bitbucket.xxx:9022/"]
     insteadOf = https://bitbucket.xxx/
```

both didn't work, without the `.gitconfig` it shows error:

```
go: bitbucket.xxx/yyy/zzz/aaa/bbb@v0.0.0-20220728131025-25f2fba58852: invalid version: git ls-remote -q origin in /home/asd/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/be703481c10c8d59451fefcffbf5e7341aab5edf1c25acbaa8356c8fbeef42d2: exit status 128:
        fatal: could not read Username for 'https://bitbucket.xxx': terminal prompts disabled
Confirm the import path was entered correctly.
If this is a private repository, see https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https for additional information.
```

if using access token on `.gitconfig`, the error is:

```
go: bitbucket.xxx/yyy/zzz/aaa/bbb@v0.0.0-20220728131025-25f2fba58852: invalid version: git ls-remote -q origin in /home/asd/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/be703481c10c8d59451fefcffbf5e7341aab5edf1c25acbaa8356c8fbeef42d2: exit status 128:
        fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://bitbucket.xxx/scm/yyy/zzz.git/'
```

^ cannot `git clone https://bitbucket.xxx/scm/yyy/zzz.git` properly using this, password or access token always rejected

if using ssh on `.gitconfig`, the error is:

```
go: bitbucket.xxx/yyy/zzz/aaa/bbb@v0.0.0-20220728131025-25f2fba58852: invalid version: git ls-remote -q origin in /home/asd/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/be703481c10c8d59451fefcffbf5e7341aab5edf1c25acbaa8356c8fbeef42d2: exit status 128:
        Repository not found
        The requested repository does not exist, or you do not have permission to access it.
        fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
        
        Please make sure you have the correct access rights
        and the repository exists.
```

I can `git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.xxx:9022/yyy/zzz.git` normally using this `.gitconfig`, but failed if using `go mod` (or when using IntelliJ).

`xxx` is the organization domain name, the organization enforced to use password on ssh key.

Did I missed something? Or how can I force `go mod` to clone/download using ssh instead of https?

Comment: See you have found a solution but figured it was worth noting that I've found this to be a lot simpler with [git credential manager](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager) (it handles authentication for the https requests so there is no need to map to ssh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, the `.gitconfig` is wrong, it should be like this:

```
[url "ssh://git@bitbucket.xxx:9022/"]
    insteadOf = https://bitbucket.xxx/scm/
```

^ in my case, there is `scm` in the suffix.

now can `git clone https://bitbucket.xxx/scm/yyy/zzz.git` properly, with `go mod` also works.